# Devise Masquerade with multiple devise models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have an admin devise model and a user devise model. I am trying to use devise_masquerade gem to login as users to help with support but can't seem to get it working between the two devise models. Has anybody had any experience with this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Probably it could be helpful to use this issue link from devise_masquerade:

https://github.com/oivoodoo/devise_masquerade/issues/50

```
config.masquerading_resource_class=Admin
config.masqueraded_resource_class=User
```